# Extracting custom HTTP Headers to be used in a DSS service

Tags: http, curl, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-api-manager

We have a WOS2 DSS service which is used as the backend of an API created in WSO2 APIM. Since management wanted to create a custom http headers (username,passwd) which will be used to verify if the users is authorized based on a db data. How can I extract header data and pass it to the dss service as a parameter to be used in the query for authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [custom sequence](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Adding+Mediation+Extensions) option. Define your mediation logic and store that in registry. And when publishing API use that sequence.

When defining mediation logic, extract that particular http header and make that to available in the request URL. Use, [HTTP endpoints](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/HTTP+Endpoint) for that. Define properties in your custom sequence, which can extract values from your custom header.